# How To Pick Custom Size Of Uploaded Image In Theme Via the_post_thumbnail();?

Tags: theme-development, post-thumbnails, media, images

I am designing a magazine style theme and I want different image sizes as to show on `index.php` page. Now for this, I am using `<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 100) );?>` but it is picking 150x150 images not 100x100 images. So How to pick my desired different size of images that are uploaded before not after the theme using?

Note: My default media setting in WordPress blog is 150x150, 300x300, 1024x1024 respectively for thumbnail, medium, large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use add_image_size() function to create custom sized images. You only need to paste some piece of codes in your functions.php and then update the template files accordingly.

For example :

```
add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300 ); // 300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true ); // (cropped)
```

And you can use below codes to load those images in your template.

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' ); 
the_post_thumbnail( 'homepage-thumb' );
```

Hope this helps. See [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) page for more info.

Comment: Your Code Is Not Re-sizing MY Old Uploaded Images. I Want Then In A New Size Also...

Comment: Yes, it won't re-size the existing images. But it will work for the new images you're adding. Can you please try this plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ , may be this will help you to re-size old images too. But please take a backup before doing so.